# How to assign value to class property of an element in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular

```
<google-signin 
    height  = ""
    width   = ""
    theme   = ""
    signedIn= ""
    brand   = ""
    needAdditionalAuth = "" class = "{{_class}}">
</google-signin>
```

In the directive-

```
ngOnInit(){
    this._class = "height-" + this._height + " width-" + this._width + " theme-" + this._theme + " signedIn-" + this._signedIn + " brand-" + this._brand + "  additionalAuth-" + this._needAdditionalAuth;
}
```

I want to compute the class of the googleSignin element based on the attribute values provided. This computed class string would then reference a few classes defined in a css file.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `[ngClass]="_class"`

```
<google-signin 
    height  = ""
    width   = ""
    theme   = ""
    signedIn= ""
    brand   = ""
    needAdditionalAuth = "" [ngClass]="_class">
</google-signin>
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/JD2zBQ?p=preview)
If you investigate the DOM you'll see that `class="yyy"` is added.

Comment: The above approach does not work. Won't it treat "_class" as a field value, try find an "_class" in css and assign that ? I want to bind it to a variable _class value. Also if I use [ngClass] = "{_class : true}", then it assigns the value "_class" to class. ie class = "_class"

Comment: That's what `[...]` around `ngClass` does.

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks Gunter. This method works. I have a question though. Why do e need use interpolation here [ngClass] = "{{_class}]" ?

Comment: You can either use `[propName]="expression"` or `propName="{{expression}}"` but a combination doesn't work. `[ ]` already indicate to Angular it needs to interpret the value. With `[...]="{{...}}"` it interprets `{{ }}` as part of the expression. If you use `propName="{{expression}}"` expression is converted to a string before it's assigned. In your case the 2nd form `ngClass="{{_class}}"` probably works as well. I just prefer `[]` over `{{}}` because usually you don't want the value be stringified. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks Gunter. I understand this concept better now.

Comment: Hey Gunter, Annother thing I noticed. if I do this <google-signin [ngClass] = "_class"> it does not bind the property at all. However if I define a div in the template of google signin directive, it binds the property appropriately.

Comment: I don't think there is a difference. Can you create a plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: No prob :D, glad to hear you figured it out.

Comment: if you  can spare some time. Could You look at this. Its from Theiry's response.  ---------Hi Theiry, You approach works as well. But I came across a new challenge .plnkr.co/edit/jOlEWZzilTId3gruhu9B?p=preview . If I assign more than 1 value example: this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elt.nativeElement, 'height-' + this._height + " brand-"+this._brand, true);. I get an error in console. You can view the same in plunkr. Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList':. My intent is to add multiple classes the the element based on the input values. However I do not face this issue in Gunters method.

Comment: I had a look but I didn't understand what the problem is or why you would want to use this approach.

Comment: I am not using this approach. Discussing purely for educational purposes. If I use-  this.renderer.setElementClass(nativeElem, "height-tall brand-google", true), to apply multiple css classes. It throws an error-  Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('height-tall brand-google') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.

Comment: It requires an array of strings `this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elt.nativeElement, ["height-tall", "brand-google"], true)`. As the error messages states, spaces are not supported in class names. https://plnkr.co/edit/yilbvcy5xmnAWMMALjNP?p=preview

Comment: Thanks once again Gunter.

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage the `Renderer` class within your component. The latter needs to define inputs for each attribute and react on updates based on the `ngOnChanges` method:

```
@Input('height') {
_height: string;

(...)

constructor(private renderer:Renderer, private elt:ElementRef) {
}

ngOnChanges(){
  // Remove the previous class if any for "height"
  if (this.previousHeightClass) {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elt.nativeElement,
                       this.previousHeightClass, false);
  }
  // Add the new class for "height"
  this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elt.nativeElement,
                       'height-' + this._height, true);
  (...)
  // Save the previous class for "height
  this.previousHeightClass = "height-" + this._height;
}
```

You can use your component this way:

```
<google-signin 
  [height]  = "height"
  (...)
  [needAdditionalAuth] = "needAdditionalAuth">
</google-signin>
```

You can update `height` using an input for testing:

```
<google-signin 
  [height]  = "height">
</google-signin>

<input [(ngModel)]="height" value="test"/>
```

The class are added / removed accordingly...

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/jOlEWZzilTId3gruhu9B?p=preview.

Comment: I update my answer with a new approach and provide a plunkr. In fact the _class property is internally to your component. In your provide the Renderer class could help you...

Comment: Hi Theiry, You approach works as well. But I come across a new challenge .https://plnkr.co/edit/jOlEWZzilTId3gruhu9B?p=preview . If I assign a value ex: this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elt.nativeElement,
                       'height-' + this._height + " brand-"+this._brand, true);. I get an error in console. You can view the same in plunkr.  Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList':. My intent is to add multiple classes the the element based on the input values. However I do not face this issue in Gunters method.

Comment: What is actually the new challenge? ;-)

Comment: Hey Theiry any clue ? How this can be circumvented ?